# Why doesn't the Apple Watch activity app count the activity recorded on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, health.app, apple-watch, activity.app

When walking around with the iPhone and not the Apple Watch the iPhone records steps. However when looking at the Apple Watch activity app the previously recorded steps are not shown there. Why is that?

Comment: [*tags discussion*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21295662#21295662)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The activity recorded on the Apple Watch is separate from the activity recorded on the iPhone. As such each is recorded as a separate source in health.app. Also only activity recorded on the Apple Watch is reflected in activity.app.

Source: [@pbur](https://twitter.com/pbur) - Apple Software Engineer

https://twitter.com/wahoo/status/591749264956461058

Comment: So there's NO integration between Health and Activity?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius There is. Measurements from the watch flow to the health app and measurements from the phone flow to the health app. Then only measurements where the source is the watch flow to the Activity app.

Comment: So no flow of information from tracking on the phone to the Activity app (on Watch or iOS), right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius correct

Comment: Thanks. Just one more clarification: You say that all the flow (from both watch and phone) goes through the *Health app first*, and *only then* from the Health app to the Activity app (and only if they come from the Watch). Do I have that right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius that sounds correct. I think this is why the Activity app doesn't even appear unless you pair a watch with your phone.

Comment: So does this mean that an app (say [Cyclemeter](https://abvio.com/cyclemeter/)) that [has a Watch UI](https://abvio.com/applewatch/) and *appears* to be recording data that is available to the Activity app is in fact not doing so (since in that case the Watch is not the source)? That seems to me what is going on (for example I get notifications to stand in the middle of 30mph sprints!); but if it's true it means that none of the third party fitness apps integrate in any way with Activity!

Comment: Actually, it appears even worse than that: If I put a third-party app (like Cyclometer) first in the list of datasources in Heath (the only way to get its results in Health at all) it *blocks data from the Watch*, **even when the third-party app is off**. So if I run but don't don't use the third-party app to log it, Heath does not capture any of the data from the activity. Incredible.